# How can I upgrade my device to Apple iOS 5?

Tags: 11.04, ipod, apple, iphone

How can I download and install the new version of iOS (iOS 5) on my iPod using my Ubuntu system? Do I have to give up and just find a Mac OS / Windows machine?

Relevant details:

- iPod touch 4th-gen
- Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I used a friend's computer. Upgrading a major iOS version erases all music though. The only things that are backed up are contacts, photos, and settings. It assumes you'll just resync after updating. But getting music on the iPod is fairly easy in comparison, so I'm not too upset.

Comment: I was actually thinking about this earlier. haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible to execute an upgrade on a Linux machine, but you can always create an instance Windows 7/xp/whatever on say VirtualBox and upgrade from there.

Comment: But that requires that I own a copy of a Windows OS right?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. But you can always download a trial version if you are going to use it just for an upgrade.

Comment: Easier than buying a whole Mac though …

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this will be the last time any iOS operating system will require a connection to update. After you've upgrade to iOS 5 you won't ever have to do it again. Sadly, I'm afraid you are just going to have to bite the bullet and virtualize a Windows machine or borrow a Mac.